# Canvas image back to original from grayscale/invert etc.?

Tags: html5-canvas

Every post I came across writes about grayscaling an image. But no one ever speaks about returning from grayscale or brighten/invert etc. adjustment. How should one reverse the effects to get back the original? I can just reset my original img src, but that affects a lot of other things. If I had cropped my image earlier, resetting it to original is not really a good idea!

Note: I know how to grayscale/brighten/adjust gamma etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grayscale conversion is a lossy operation and you will lose all the RGB information. So, you cannot return it to the original form.

As for brighten/invert, you can just do darken/invert again to get back the original.

Comment: Thanks! If I brighten an image to a certain level, darkening it by that same level will reproduce my original image?

Comment: It should. But the level will be different in both cases, as the value will be a percentage of the actual image brightness.